# Is it OK to paint bedroom plain yellow?

Tags: painting, bedroom

I have a 4 by 3 m room which I painted yellow. However it's only the first layer of paint, but when I'm in the room (in the daylight) my skin and my clothes reflects that yellow like there's a yellow lightbulb and if I stay a little bit in there I feel dizzy because it's too strong and sharp for the eyes.

So I have some really bugging questions now:

Is this because there's no furniture and all the color falls directly on the eyes? Will it be milder and less noticeable in the context with the furniture and stuff? Will everything have the color "on it's own" after I fill the room? This happens with every plain color or it's only the yellow?

I can't afford to change it now, the decision is already made. I can however, fade it out with white. Would this help?

Comment: Yes, the yellow walls will significantly tint the room's light, so everything will look yellow.   This is why bold colors are so rarely used in interior spaces.  Bad colors can cause psychological issues such as the burning desire to engage in DIY painting projects.  Here in America, paint is $30 a gallon, roller-tray-brush kits are $10 and plastic tarps about $5.

Comment: @Andrei I think this question would be more on topic here and would get more answers if it is reworded to ask "I am not happy with paint color-what can I do?" This is more or less what you are asking, but the way the title reads it appears you are asking for opinions on the color yellow, which is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I just painted my two youngest boys' room an intense goldenrod. It is a small room, and with only one window and slanted ceilings, it tends to be dark and closed in. I *wanted* to brighten the room, but I can understand that if that wasn't the desired effect the color can be overwhelming.

I personally find yellow to be a difficult color to tolerate for long periods of time; I believe that studies have shown that yellow can make people feel anxious. Here's a link http://www.colorpsychology.org/yellow/ that provides more insight.

If you already know that you don't love the color but can't afford to waste the paint, I would suggest you take it back to the paint store and ask them to tone it down for you, rather than just add white. Most paint stores or counters in big box stores will do this for free, however there is some skill involved and you might have better results at a store that exclusively specializes in paint.

To a certain extent, yes, adding furniture, paintings/photos, and curtains will break up the color and reduce the feeling of being inside an egg yolk, but, if it's enough to make you comfortable w/the color is questionable. The yellow may very well make some of the colors of other items look different; this may be good or bad.

You might try changing the lighting in the room. If there are windows, try diffusing the light with sheer curtains or shades. Light bulbs, both LED and incandescent, are available in "warm" or "cool" tones that might make the room feel totally different.

For some tips on how to decorate to "harmonize" the color, check out the Houzz app, which allows you to search through thousands of photos of homes. You can type in "yellow walls" and it'll show you what others have done, both professional interior decorators and regular folk, for inspiration and solutions.

If nothing helps, don't despair, I've made plenty of bad color choices in my day, and on a tight budget to boot, and I'm still sane (I think). I just wait a while and then repaint as soon as my budget and schedule allow it. That's the beauty of paint vs wallpaper-it's low commitment.

Comment: Cultural differences are everything. In china, red is the color of happiness, while in many other places, red is the color of hunger and aggression. I have heard yellow is the color of happiness, energy, and creativity, and I have heard that it was the color of anxiety and insanity. In general, this is a perfect answer, though. +Jax/She-ra

Comment: I'm not from China, or of Chinese descent, but I sure do agree with red being the color of happiness, 'specially when it comes to my mustang (turbo red exterior, red leather interior-driving that car makes me happy happy happy!)  thanks for the props!

Comment: First of all, i'm sorry that i answered so late. I had connexion issues. Second, thank you for your answers! About my dilema: I added white and it looks just amazing.